# Ограничения на имена каталогов Apache+php

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Есть ли ограничение на имя каталога  "php"?

Дело в том, что если я пытаюсь обратиться в файлу проекта через Интернет, введя в адресной строке *адрес сайта/php/* ? то мне выведет ошибку 403, если я обращаюсь к файлам по этому же адресу, но хранящимся в каталоге с другим названием (например, *адрес сайта/page/*), то они будут мне показаны. К каталогу php я могу получить доступ из других файлов через include().

Никаких запретов в httpd.conf не нашла, а .htaccess в проекте отсутствует

Comment: 403 - это ошибка доступа. Скорее всего, нет прав на папку у веб-сервера.

Comment: Не подскажите, где эти настройки можно найти?

Comment: Повторюсь, запрета в  httpd.conf  нет, а htaccess отсутствует. Никакие другие файлы для настройки на сервере не используются

Comment: права на чтение каждого файла и права на чтение списка файлов в директории это разные вещи. при вызове `example.com/php/` вы хотите что бы  был показан список файлов в директории? или у вас любой вызов `example.com/php/test.php` заканчивается 403 ошибкой?

Comment: @ilyaplot тогда и инклудом бы не работали.

Comment: любой вызов _example.com/php/test.php_ заканчивается ошибкой 403

Answer (score 0):

Перечисляю алгоритм запуска сайта, проверьте каждый этап на своём сервере. Необходимо отредактировать права доступа, чтобы убедиться, что доступ на чтение разрешен к общей веб-директории и всем файлам и папкам, содержащимся в ней. Это необходимо для того, чтобы страницы сайта отображались корректно:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Теперь ваш веб-сервер должен иметь разрешения, необходимые для отображения контента. Кроме того, теперь ваш пользователь имеет возможность создавать контент в необходимых директорий.

Проверьте создан ли у Вас файл:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Включите сайт:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
```

и перезагрузите сервер:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: не пойму, как  это поможет разрешить доступ к каталогу?

Comment: @nita для начала посмотри какие права выставлены у твоего каталога, имя пользователя выполняющий запрос, при совпадении должно всё работать ( плюс то что в ответе), нет исправь(как в ответе)

Comment: у меня Apache на Windows 7, виртуальный  хост прописан так же как у вас, намек на запрет доступа конкретно к каталогу "php"  в настройках не найден. Если бы не было доступа к проекту, то, наверное,  не было бы доступа и к остальным каталогам, но они вполне себе доступны

Comment: @nita иногда сохраняются права при копировании или распаковки, поэтому я бы не стал пренебрегать этой проверки.